# HDBSCAN approximate_predict always returning probability of 0

Tags: python, scikit-learn, hdbscan

I am using [HDBSCAN](https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/hdbscan) to generate prediction data for a given cluster model. I then attempt to classify new points using the `approximate_predict` function to find the correct cluster for a new point. The model returns the correct cluster for a new point but the probability/strength is always 0.0. To generate the model and classify new points I use:

```py
# Generate the model
cluster_model = hdbscan.HDBSCAN(metric='euclidean', min_cluster_size=3, cluster_selection_epsilon=0.4,
                                prediction_data=True).fit(data)

# Classify new point
cluster, prob = hdbscan.approximate_predict(cluster_model, new_point)
print(cluster, prob)
```

As I understand, if the strength/probability is 0.0 the point has been classified as noise. From manual analysis of the new points I can see they do fit into the heart of the original clusters so I don't understand why the probability is always 0.0?

Comment: You meant `print(cluster, prob)`, yes?